# Python library for unpacking UPX-packed binaries?

Tags: library, python

I'm looking for a Python library to unpack [UPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPX)-packed binaries.

**Requirements:**

- Python 2 or 3 is fine
- I'd prefer the unpacking is all handled via Python code
- The unpacking method should not execute the binary as part of unpacking it (with the exception of setting a breakpoint just after it unpacks itself but before the unpacked code executes).